# How to intagrate angular 2 with JADE/PUG template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, pug

I am developing an application in nodejs expressjs framework with mongodb backend. i'll receive data from mongodb and pass as model of for JADE template it will render the page.

I want to integrate Angular 2 for form validation, live search, filters and some of DOM modification. I am not sure we can target the DOM element directly to init angular application without specifying template like angular 1 .

Could someone please help me how to init angular2  in already rendered html jade.

Comment: you just want to render HTML from backend side ?

Comment: @PardeepJain Yes, HTML will be generated from sever side. I want to manage few part for the page from angularjs example search area and forms.

Comment: @DineshKumar Angular 2 supports server-side rendering already. Trying to use Jade with it is the wrong approach.